# How to remove a tick on a dog?

Tags: dogs, health, parasites, ticks

Since I have my dog I check him for [ticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick) when we're back from walks in the backcountry. So today I noticed one, then after checking carefully another one. Hopefully there is no other.

So the question was: what should I do to remove it ?

I had to improvise a bit. I used tweezers, trying to get it as close to the skin as possible (to remove the whole beast). Is there a better way ?

Here is what I removed.

[image]

Comment: Related [Tick removal, to twist or not twist?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/tick-removal-to-twist-or-not-twist)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a lot of ticks in the South-West Finland and so I have been removing ticks from our dogs on regular basis every spring. We never seem to treat the dogs with tick repellent early enough.

To remove ticks I have used normal tweezers, special ["tick-tweezers"](http://www.trixie.de/en/prod/Dog_Tick_Tweezers,13060), bare fingernails and a tick lasso. So far the absolutely best device for removing ticks has been [a tick lasso](http://www.wagthedoguk.com/dont-get-ticked-off-remove-ticks-from-dogs-with-a-tick-lasso/). I'm not affiliated with the company named in the picture, but for the old saying; a picture talks a thousand words. A tick lasso:

[image]

Using this device is easy, safe, almost 100% success, and you don't even need protective gloves in hand. Push the button on the other end of the "pen" and a lasso of a thin nylon string will come out from the other end. Ease the lasso over the tick so that it goes around the tick near the dog's skin. Release the button, which tightens the lasso, and raise the pen straight outwards from the skin, then rotate the "pen" while simultaneously pulling gently out. Tick comes out whole, usually still alive even. Drop the tick in a toilet and flush.

I have removed ticks from real tough places, like from the corner of a dog's eye, where you would not dare go with normal tweezers. I won't recommend anything but a lasso for removing ticks.

[image]
<sub>Red dot = tick</sub>

Comment: I would seriously avoid bare hands. Some of the diseases that can be transmitted via a tick are dangerous to humans and a cut or break in the skin on your fingers is a vector to illness.

Comment: Ah, but that's the beauty of tick lasso. You don't come even close to touching the tick.

Comment: Just mentioned it with respect to your comment that you've done that. :)

Comment: I see, yeah, desperate measures when nothing else was available. Definitely not recommendable.

Comment: Related [Tick removal, to twist or not twist?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/tick-removal-to-twist-or-not-twist)

Answer (score 5):

According the *Blackwell's Five-Minute Veterinary Consult: Canine and Feline* the process is to grasp the tick as close to the skin as possible with tweezers and **gently** pull free.

So, I would wear disposable gloves and using blunt-tipped tweezers (to protect the skin of the dog), gently grasp the tick body and gently pull in the opposite direction of the mandibles. Avoid crushing the body of the tick.

If the head of the tick breaks off and remains, don't panic, it will be ejected in a few days and it's very rare in any event. You should wash the area with a small amount of hydrogen peroxide (use a cotton swab) and then apply a little bit of neosporin. A small bump may remain, but it should disappear in a couple of days.

Keep an eye on your friend. As your follow up question asked, there's quite a lot of diseases associated with ticks, and so if you see anything out of place, get him to a vet ASAP.