# What are the effects of ticks on dogs and does it transmit diseases?

Tags: dogs, health, parasites, ticks

I recently [removed two ticks](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/how-to-remove-a-tick-on-a-dog) from my dog.

What are their effects on dogs healths? I heard about *tick poisoning*.

Apart from these direct effects, do they transmit other diseases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh yes, ticks are quite an issue for dogs. Some diseases that may be transmitted by ticks include:

- [Canine babesiois](http://www.testapet.com/test/babesiosis.htm)
- [Rocky mountain spotted fever](http://www.petmd.com/dog/conditions/infectious-parasitic/c_dg_rocky_mountain_spotted_fever)
- [Canine monocytic ehrlichiosis](http://www.ivis.org/advances/infect_dis_carmichael/waner/ivis.pdf)
- [Cyclic thrombocytopenia](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/infectious+cyclic+thrombocytopenia)
- [Granulocytic anaplasmosis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19761477)
- [Lyme disease](http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/id-mi/lyme-fs-eng.php)
- [American canine hepatozoonosis](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC207105/)
- [Canine hepatozoonosis](http://www.merckmanuals.com/vet/circulatory_system/blood_parasites/old_world_hepatozoonosis_and_american_canine_hepatozoonosis.html)
- [Tick paralysis](http://www.petmd.com/dog/conditions/infectious-parasitic/c_dg_tick_paralysis)

Many of these associated issues may also effect humans if the ticks transfer from the dog to the human. So, be *very* wary of that and be vigilant in keeping your dog tick free.

More localized effects is that the tick can leave a small pimple-like mound that should go away in a day or two. Might be a little itchy. If it doesn't go away in a couple of days, take the dog to the vet. After tick removal, watch your dog carefully for signs of illness (e.g. not eating, vomiting, etc.).